# Proof of the first Sylow's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Our teacher taught us about Wielandt's proof for Sylow's theorem. And our homework is to give an alternate proof. Our teacher gave us two steps. And I have already done the first part:

> Let $H \le G$ and $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then the
>   intersection of $H$ and some conjugate of $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup
>   of $H$.

Then how to use this conclusion to prove the first Sylow's Theorem? I am thinking to use  $G$ acts conjugation on $X=\{$all the subset of $G$ with $\vert G \vert_p $ elements $\}$. But I failed to get any useful information. How this conclusion relates to the existence of a Sylow $p$-subgroup? Either hints or comments would be alright. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement of the 'first part' you claim to have done does not make much sense to me. Could you explain what you mean by this statement? I mean, the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ and its subgroups (for example the trivial subgroup) are in general not conjugate.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I am very sorry to miss a part: it's the conjugate of P "intersects with H" is the Sylow p-subgroup of H.

Comment: You might consider editing your question accordingly. In any case, for me, Sylow's first theorem is about the existence of Sylow $p$-subgroups. But the statement of the 'first part' already talks about a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Could you clarify this?  By the way, you should refrain from talking about 'the' Sylow $p$-subgroup since there is not a unique one in general.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I'm a new here and I haven't found any place to edit my question. How to edit it? And this is why I confused with my homework. But I am guessing it might be related to: If there's a Sylow p-subgroup, then all of Sylow p-groups are conjugate.

Comment: This is what is usually called Sylow's second theorem. If you want to prove this, the 'first part' is actually helpful by choosing $H$ and $P$ both to be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch What I mean is that if there exists a Sylow p-group then the Sylow's second theorem is true. But I am wondering that whether Sylow's first theorem can be result from this way.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but not that easy. For any finite group $G$ you would have to find a finite group $G'$ of which you know that it posses a Sylow $p$-subgroup and for which $G$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $G'$. Then you could use your 'first part' statement to conclude the existence of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ (as long as you did not assume its existence during the proof of the statement, of course).

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch My first thought was to find such a $G'$. But I failed to countinue for I haven't had any clue of finding such a group. As I've already known that $GL(n,p)$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup, is there any revalent between these two?

Comment: @Johnny, to your last question, the answer is yes. Given a finite group $H$ of order $n$, the (right) regular representation is an injective homomorphism into the symmetric group $S_{n}$, so that $H$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $S_{n}$, and then $S_{n}$  is (isomorphic to) the subgroup of $GL(n, p)$ given by the so-called permutation matrices (in other words, $S_{n}$ permutes the indices of the elements of a given basis).

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks a lot for your help! I found it just a while after asking that question. And it seems sufficient to consider $S_n$, because $\langle (1,2,..., \vert S_n \vert_p ) \rangle$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Johnny, yes, you can only consider $S_{n}$, but it's rather more complicated - as you've written it, it looks a like a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{n}$ is cyclic, which is not always the case, see $n = 4$ and $p = 2$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti You're right. I've got a little too excited and too casual about it.